# A program that passes two integer arrays to a function that then copies the values common in both into a third array and displays it in int main()

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void myfunction(int array[], int array1[], int array2[], int, int, int);
int main()
{
    int array[5], array1[5], array2[5];
    cout << "Enter array:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
        cin >> array1[i];
    }
    myfunction(array, array1, array2, 5, 5, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << array2[i];
}
void myfunction(int array[], int array1[], int array2[], int n, int m, int o)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == array1[j])
                array2[k] = array1[j];
            k++;
        }
    for (int i = k + 1; i < o; i++)
        array2[i] = 0;
}
```

This is the logic that I thought of. But it is giving segmentation error which I don't know about. Also, I don't know where I am wrong. Please guide me

Comment: What input produces the error ? (btw, when you fill array2, you might go out of bounds, consider the case where all elements of array1 and array2 are the same)

Comment: Use your debugger to figure out which line segfaults.

Comment: I used values 1 2 3 1 2 for first array and 1 1 1 1 1 for the second array
the compiler gave 1 1 1 1 1 but if I enter 2 2 2 2 2 for the 2nd array it gives segmentation fault

Comment: Could you tell us what output you would expect with those two arrays ?

Comment: Other than people here tend to have a lot of experience and can see some errors at a glance; they would use exactly the same debugging method as you; which is documented (roughly) here https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Learning how to debug programs will save you hours

Comment: Why do you use raw arrays and not `std::vector`?

Comment: We have not been taught about that "std::vector"

Comment: Btw, in addition to HolyBlackCat and UKMonkey advices, compiling with clang and the "-fsanitize=address" flag then running your program through a debugger (e.g. lldb) is wonderful when you got seemingly random segfaults in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have one major issue here:

```
if(array[i]==array1[j])
    array2[k]=array1[j];
    k++;
```

The `k++` part is executed each time but should be done once per `array` iteration only when a match is found. This is the part that is giving you the seg fault.

You can fix the whole nested for like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++k)
{
    const auto val = array[i];
    if (std::any_of(array1, array1+n, [&val](int v){return v == val;}))
        array2[k] = array[i];
    else
        array2[k] = 0;
}
```

Considering you don't use `c++11` you can write an equivalent of the above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++k)
{
    bool match = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    {
       if (array[i] == array1[j])
       {
           match = true;
           break;
       }
    }

    if (match)
        array2[k] = array[i];
    else
        array2[k] = 0;
}
```

This way you can also skip the following loop which also had an issue:

```
for (int i = k + 1; i < o; i++)
```

In result for input data like `{1, 2, 3, 3, 5}` and `{1, 2, 4, 4, 5}` you should get `{1, 2, 0, 0, 5}` which according to your comment is the expected output.

In general, I'd suggest you use `std::vector` or `std::array` since you work with a const sized array. This way you won't have to pass the array sizes as hardcoded values here and there. Additionally you'll be able to use the foreach-like loops and the code will get a bit cleaner.

Comment: It worked. But the order is changed
I used 6 7 8 9 0 for both arrays
but the answer returned is 6 8 0 7 9

Comment: I don't think it is enough. E.g. if array={0,0,0,0,0}, array1={0,0,0,0,0}, then the inner loop body will be executed 25 times, and the condition will always be true. Leading you to try setting array2[0]...array2[24] to 0.

Comment: For 0 0 0 0 0 it is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: What should I do then to stop array2 from increasing from the specified index

Comment: @HaziqAhmed Not sure what you mean by that. Please explain it with an example. Edit your post for that. Do you expect my example to give in result `{1, 2, 0, 0, 5}` or `{1, 2, 5, 0, 0}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in the below `for` loops:-

```
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
     {
           if(array[i]==array1[j])
           array2[k]=array1[j];
              k++;//this is being incremented each iteration
      }
   for(int i=k+1; i<o; i++)//What are you doing here I = 5 + 1 = 6
   array2[i]=0;// what will happened here it will not execute
```

correct it like below:-

```
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
 for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
 {
       if(array[i]==array1[j])
       {
          array2[k]=array1[j];
          k++;
       }
  }
```